# UICollectionView method (collectionView cellForItemAt indexPath ) not called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to make a custom bar menu using `UICollectionView`,the problem is that cells not showed  method `collectionView  cellForItemAt indexPath` not called.

My code so far:

```
import UIKit
private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class MenuBar : UIView ,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

   lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero , collectionViewLayout : layout)
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return cv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(collectionView)
        setUpCollectionViewConstraints()
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: frame.height/2, height: frame.height)
    }

    fileprivate func setUpCollectionViewConstraints() {
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[cv]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: ["cv" : collectionView])
        let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat:"V:|[cv]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: ["cv" : collectionView])
        addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)
        addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the frame visible of your UICollectionView (you can check with https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html). You may want to call a `reloadData()`.

Comment: yes UICollectiioView is visible i checked that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check :

Your layout should be like below.

You used `UICollectionViewLayout`.

You have to use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
```

Comment: i spended two hours of determining why my coll.view not working, literally by scanning each character in sample project.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the **datasource** has something wrong.

Your **MenuBar** is on a **ViewController** right?

You may not set collectionView's **datasource** to **MenuBar**(**Delegate** too). You might set collectionView's **datasource** to a **ViewController**.